# Где безопаснее всего хранить базу данных?

Tags: база-данных, безопасность

Например, всякие хостеры могут закрыть хостинг на обслуживание, на хостинг может совершиться аттака....этот список можно продолжать до бесконечности. А тогда где же наиболее безопасно хранить базу данных. Я не говорю о 100% уверенности, такой надежности сейчас нигде нет =), но наиболее безопасные места все-таки выделить, наверное, можно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не покупайте хостинг у **всяких** хостеров, покупайте у невсяких! Данные так или иначе будут храниться на сервере! Жаль, но как данные хранить в космосе и получать их от туда телепатически еще не придумали! И еще раз повторю, данные хранятся на сервере, и они будут хранится на том сервере на который Вас хватит денег!

Comment: "Невсякие" хостеры знают, что они таковы, и, поэтому завышают свои цены в разы...на обычных же хостеров рассчитывать не приходится: то они что-то ремонтируют, то отключают, то перезагружают сервер.

Comment: Есть такое понятие как "Цена - Качество"...